# github - Is it possible to track visitors of my repo?

Tags: github

I just found **Traffic** section in **Graphs** at github repo.

And I also found that there is **Visitor** section.

I wonder if it is possible to get the information of visitors of the repo.
(i.e. who visited my repo)

Is it possible?

Comment: Use [gitnotifier.io](https://gitnotifier.io/) .You get email notifications when someone stars or forks one of your GitHub repos and follows/unfollows you. That way you can know someone visited your repo and then have a look at their profile. Github doesn’t provide such notification inbuilt, so gitnotifier is very helpful.

Comment: @user3382203 No, I don't want to know who star/fork/follow my repo, but  the information of visitor. Just visitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Github [introduced](https://github.com/blog/1672-introducing-github-traffic-analytics) visitors tracking you are only able to see unique visits, but not who exactly visited your repo.